# Unsure what page hierarchy to use with CPT UI to show on front end

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I created a custom post type using the CPT UI plugin and chose to add Categories as well. In my menu structure I have a second level item which is a category and a third level item which is the actual record or page the user should go to. On the front end the path looks like:

mysite.com/accommodation/theplace

There is no mention of the category in this url(not sure if that is a problem)

I have tried using single.php, archive.php, archive-accommodation.php and single-accommodation.php and putting some content onto all of those pages. However, it keeps going back to the home page.

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_accommodation() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Accommodation.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Accommodation", "mySite" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Accommodation", "mySite" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Accommodation", "mySite" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Accommodation", "mySite" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => false,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => true,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "accommodation", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => true,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-store",
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "custom-fields", "page-attributes", "post-formats" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "category" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "accommodation", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_accommodation' );
```

Comment: What is the custom post type named? (It might be `accommodation`, but it might also be `{some_prefix_}accommodation`.)

Comment: @PatJ, I have updated the original question with the code

Comment: Well, according to the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/), you should be able to use `single-accommodation.php` for the single post and `archive-accommodation.php` for the post type archive. Have you tried [re-saving your permalinks](https://typerocket.com/flushing-permalinks-in-wordpress/)?

Comment: Yeah, I would have thought so but it isn't working. I tried the re-saving of permalinks but still doesn't work

Comment: You have `has_archive` set to false, which means there won't be an archive for that post type. If you do want one, try `unregister_post_type()` to clear it out first, then re-register with `has_archive` set to true. Your slug/rewrite scenario shouldn't cause any problems using `single-accommodation.php` so I would double-check spelling (maybe you left out a C or M in the PHP template) and clear site cache, then check `functions.php` to make sure nothing weird like a `template_include` is going on.